# Array multiplication - what is the best algorithm?

Tags: ruby

I have to make a multiplication of n arrays.

Example :

- input = ["a", "b", "c"] * ["1", "2"] * ["&", "(", "$"]
- output = ["a1&", "a1(", "a1$", "a2&", "a2(", "a2$", "b1&", "b1(", "b1$", "b2&", "b2(", "b2$, "c1&, "c1(, "c1$, "c2&", "c2(", "c2$"]

I have created an algorithm to do that, it works good.

```
# input
entries = ["$var1$", "$var2$", "$var3$"]
data = [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2"], ["&", "(", "$"]]

num_combinaison = 1
data.each { |item| num_combinaison = num_combinaison * item.length  }

result = []
for i in 1..num_combinaison do
  result.push entries.join()
end

num_repetition = num_combinaison
data.each_index do |index|
  item = Array.new(data[index])
  num_repetition = num_repetition / item.length
  for i in 1..num_combinaison do
    result[i-1].gsub!(entries[index], item[0])
    if i % num_repetition == 0
      item.shift
      item = Array.new(data[index]) if item.length == 0
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure there is a best way to do that, but I don't find it. I have tried to use product or flatten function without success.

Somebody see a best solution ?

Thanks for your help.

Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Array
  def * other; product(other).map(&:join) end
end

["a", "b", "c"] * ["1", "2"] * ["&", "(", "$"]
# =>
# ["a1&", "a1(", "a1$", "a2&", "a2(", "a2$", "b1&", "b1(", "b1$", "b2&",
# "b2(", "b2$", "c1&", "c1(", "c1$", "c2&", "c2(", "c2$"]
```

Comment: While this is possibly the best solution, overriding a stdlib method without, at least, preserving its original behaviour is not a great idea.

Comment: @toro2k This does exactly what OP wanted. You should comment on the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

The best algorithm you can use is implemented by the [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product) method:

```
data = [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2"], ["&", "(", "$"]]
data.first.product(*entries.drop(1)).map(&:join)
# => ["a1&", "a1(", "a1$", "a2&", "a2(", "a2$", ...
```

**Update**
A safer alternative, my first solution raises a `NoMethodError` if `data` is emtpy:

```
data.reduce { |result, ary| result.product(ary).map(&:join) }
# => ["a1&", "a1(", "a1$", "a2&", "a2(", "a2$", ...

[].reduce { |r, a| r.product(a).map(&:join) }
# => nil
```